# pywinauto typekeys not working

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to upload files to a web server.  I'm using Selenium to navigate to a page and activate the windows explorer upload dialog, and then call on pywinauto to access the window that was opened.  I've been able to do that, but I can only get it to type keys into the file name field.  I'm trying to type in the directory field so I can access specific folders, but the TypeKeys method simply does nothing. Only SendKeys seem to work, but it doesn't type the spaces.  Here's my code

```
import pywinauto.keyboard
import pywinauto
import pywinauto.mouse

def inputfileinuploader(filename):
    pwa_app = pywinauto.Application().connect(path="C:\Windows/explorer.exe")
    w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')[0]
    window = pwa_app.window(handle=w_handle)
    ctrl = window['Breadcrumb Parent']
    ctrl.TypeKeys("folder")
    pywinauto.keyboard.SendKeys(u"You Can Make A Difference 1.mp3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `type_keys` sets the focus before typing. So the problem might be in the wrong control focused. If you make sure the cursor is in right place (for example, by `ctrl.click_input()` or `ctrl.draw_outline()`) but if you suspect `type_keys` sets focus incorrectly, one possible workaround is

```
ctrl.type_keys("folder", with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
```

The same params are applicable for `SendKeys` (except `set_foreground`).